# How can I not display 'Id:' when I render my form? (same as 'ParentClass ptr:')

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have made a form (Formset actually) with modelformset_factory.
I display it with

```
  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ player_formset.management_form }}
    {% for player_form in player_formset %}
      {% for field in player_form %}
          {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
      {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Aggiungi">
  </form>
```

When it render automatically adds a field with the write **'Human ptr:'** (because my model, Player, is a subclass of Human... if I use directly Human he shows me **'Id:'**, the title is just to generalize the problem).

How can I delete this write?
I tried:

1) to use in html file the tag **{% forloop.last %}** but actually the last field is **'Delete:'** checkbox (if I use **can_delete=False** it works, but I need it)

2) change label in PlayerForm(ModelForm) Meta, but seem not working for this field. It's strange that instead works **widgets = {'human_ptr': Input(attrs={})}** but it affects the **{{ field }}** not the **{{ field.label_tag }}**

If can be useful I add all the parts of the involved code:

forms.py

```
from skeleton.models import Player
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import Input


class PlayerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'jersey_number']
        labels = {
            'first_name': 'Nome',
            'last_name': '',
            'jersey_number': 'Numero di maglia',
            'human_ptr': 'human_ptr', }

        # widgets = {'human_ptr': Input(attrs={})}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from skeleton.models import Player
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PlayerForm
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def team_area(request):
    if request.user.team is not None:
        PlayerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Player, form=PlayerForm, extra=1, can_delete=True,)
        if request.method == "POST":
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(
                request.POST,
                request.FILES,
                queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team),)

            for player_form in player_formset:
                if player_form.is_valid():
                    player = player_form.save(commit=False)
                    player.team = request.user.team

            if player_formset.is_valid():
                player_formset.save()
            return redirect('team_area:home')
        else:
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team))
        return render(request, 'team_area/team_area.html', {'player_formset': player_formset})
    else:
        return render(request, 'team_area/empty_page.html')
```

models.py

```
class Human(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (('XXS', 'XXS'), ('XS', 'XS'), ('S', 'S'), ('M', 'M'), ('L', 'L'), ('XL', 'XL'), ('XXL', 'XXL'))
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    jersey_size = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SHIRT_SIZES, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
        super(Human, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Player(Human):
    year_of_birth = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1900), MaxValueValidator(2100)], blank=True, null=True)
    jersey_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)], blank=True, null=True)
    all_star_game = models.ForeignKey(AllStarGame, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

*Possibly I would like to modify directly the form (**views.py**), not the way I display it (**team_area.html**).*

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but it works

```
 {% for field in player_form %}
     {% if field.label_tag != id %}
         {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If this can help you I tried also `field.field.label_tag != id` and happened the opposite nothing was shown

Comment: I think it's the same, if I found the solution for one I've solved also the other one

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my html file and worked. I must add the else because without the form doesn't work

```
  {% for field in player_form %}
    {% if forloop.revcounter != 2 %}
      {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% else %}
      {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```